# Help identify this plant

Tags: identification

I'm in Stockton,Ca. Last year these just appeared in my backyard..they came back this year and are bigger than last year.also in a few more places... they didn't flower last year.maybe I will get flowers this year. I'm thinking they're some sort of lily.[image][image][image]

Comment: Leaves have a slightly Bok Choy look, although that's not what it is. I suspect it's a farm escapee. What are they growing in your area?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so sure, it could be one of the *Arum*, e.g. *Arum italicum* a Mediterranean plant (probably an old cultivar), which it is now considered invasive (also in CA): See https://www.invasiveplantatlas.org/subject.html?sub=13931.

If it is not an *Arum*, I thin it is still in that family (*Araceae*), like *Calla*. As you see, the flowers are not very visible, but with a easy to recognize form (spadix). In my experience, "wild" *Arum* tend not to flower every year.